# Which plugins does Wavelab 7 have (that Wavelab Elements doesn't have)?

Tags: audio, plugins

I'm thinking about buying Wavelab 7 or Wavelab Elements 7. I'm not planning to do multi-track recordings, so I thought that Elements may be enough for me. But one major difference between the two versions appears to be that Wavelab 7 contains many more plugins (VST and others) than Wavelab Elements.

However, I can't find a comparative list of plugins anywhere that would enable me to decide whether I might need them. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick google I was able to find the following:

[Link to download Wavelab 7 manual (Chapter 12 for plug-in info)](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CD0QFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fc3.zzounds.com%2Fmedia%2FSTE_WAVELAB7_Manual-d5cd9c783ca76203ed6c1e86aaf6037c.pdf&ei=1bxJUP2bCsSn0AXQvoH4Bg&usg=AFQjCNEnUgsRqM9tSqJum6kTn_brx22TuQ)

[Wavelab Elements 7 manual (Chapter 10 for plug-in info)](ftp://ftp.steinberg.net/Download/WaveLab_Elements_7/Manuals/WaveLab-Elements-en-7.pdf)

These should give you all of the information you need to do a feature by feature comparison.

I hope this is helpful :)